# JavaScript Question dealing with different browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

The problem that I'm having is that my code works fine in JavaScript but doesn't work correctly in Firefox or safari and wondering why. What I'm doing is I have a loop going through each element and depending on the variable inside a text box just want to alert something. Like i said earlier this code works fine in IE. Here is the code below:

Here is an example of text box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMac" runat="server" req="yes" errMessage="Mac"/>

for (a = 0; a < theForm.elements.length; a++) {
  if (theForm.elements[a].type == "text" && theForm.elements[a].req == "yes") {
    alert("Made it here")
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `theForm`?  can you put the source (that asp creates) into a fiddle demo?

Comment: Could we have some more information? What version of IE does it work in, what versions of other browsers is it not working for? Have you tried only matching part of your if statement, either equal to text or req == yes alone? Have you tried an OR statement instead of an AND?

Comment: What library are you using ? Can you give us an example of the HTML markup generated by your asp tag ?

Comment: The version is of firefox is 6.0, IE is 7, Safari is 5.1. Yes I have tried (theForm.elements[a].req == "yes") by itself and found out that this is the problem, but dont understand why. I have alerted it but it comes up undefined, but I look in the source and see the variable in the textbox, so I dont understand whats going on.

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7165804/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getAttribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute) to read the custom attributes. See http://jsfiddle.net/8EWQr/.

So instead of

(theForm.elements[a].type == "text" && theForm.elements[a].req == "yes")

use

(theForm.elements[a].getAttribute('type') == "text" && theForm.elements[a].getAttribute('req') == "yes")

Answer (score 1):

I don't know asp tags. I assume req is a attribute so this should do what you asked by only alerting if the attributes are equal to your requirments, I use a shortcut array to hold all the found elements by tag name as James said its more crossbrowser.

```
var a = [];
a = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++){

if (theForm.elements[i].getAttribute('type')== "text" &&     theForm.elements[i].getAttribute('req') == "yes" ){
alert("Made it here wtih" + theForm.elements[i]) 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using document.getElementsByTagName, as I believe this is supported across all browsers.

```
var linkList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `var theForm = getElementById("theForm")` instead of calling theForm directly. Only Chrome and IE adds the elements ids to the javascript global scope.

And you should use `getAttribute()` to get the value of an attribute because only IE has this shortcut.

Try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gKw6p/15/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronfrost/Xra5y/1/
That has your answer.

Comment: Can you please add your answer here?  When your link rots away your answer will be useless...