# Javascript Question dealing with different browsers

Tags: javascript, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Question dealing with different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165804/javascript-question-dealing-with-different-browsers)

The problem im having is that I have a script that works fine in IE, but in Firefox or Safari is not working correctly. What im doing is going through the whole form and within textboxes i put a variable which im searching for. Here is an example of a textbox im using:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMac" runat="server" req="yes" errMessage="Mac"/>
```

Here is the script im using, NOTE: it works correctly in IE

```
for (a = 0; a < theForm.elements.length; a++) {
    if (theForm.elements[a].type == "text" && theForm.elements[a].req == "yes") {
        alert("Made it")
     }
 }
```